# ISPN000373: Attempted to start a cache using configuration template 'XXXX' with Infinispan 9.2.5

Tags: infinispan-9

At application startup, I attempt to create a cache like this:

The code that I use to create the cache is as follows:

```
 final Configuration entityConfiguration = myCacheManager.getCacheConfiguration( "entity" );
 Objects.requireNonNull( entityConfiguration );
 myCacheManager.createCache( "XXXX", entityConfiguration );
```

This results in the following exception:

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000373: Attempted to start a cache using configuration template 'XXXX'
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:616)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:589)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalGetCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:475)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:461)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:447)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:413)
```

I understand this exception to mean that I can not have a cache named the same as a cache template.

I looked into `org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager` (version 9.2.5.Final) and found this implementation:

```
    @Override
    public <K, V> Cache<K, V> createCache(String name, Configuration configuration) {
      defineConfiguration(name, configuration);
      return getCache(name);
    }
```

This defines a configuration with the name passed in.  In this case `"XXXX"`, and then goes on to attempt to create a cache with the exact same name.

In the call to `getCache(name)` it calls through to `wireAndStartCache` which checks if the configuration is the same as the cache name.  It always is, because the previous code passed the exact same string.  I don't understand how this method could ever possibly work.

How can I avoid this error and create a cache?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code I posted above is that `getCacheConfiguration( "entity" );` returns a template.  So you can get it to work by using a builder to effectively clone it but without the template flag set.

```
final Configuration entityTemplate = myCacheManager.getCacheConfiguration( "entity" );
Objects.requireNonNull( entityTemplate  );
final ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.read( entityTemplate );
builder.template( false );
myCacheManager.createCache( "XXXX", builder.build() );
```